# PHP: How to Insert Radio Button Value Into MySql Database

Tags: php

I want to insert selected radio button value into the database. just "yes" or "no". if anyone can give me an idea it would be a great help. I am using PHP script lampp(linux ubuntu 14.04). Thanks in advance.
[image] this is php script
[image] this is the result in localhost.
i use datbase mysql:-database_name: projet
                    -table_name: action ,who are two columns:temperature,humidity

So.. any help and thanks

Comment: Is it reading the radio button or inserting a value that gives you problems? Please reduce the scope of your question to just the problematic stuff. Also, don't post pictures of text but rather include the similarly reduced text.

Comment: Hi Ulrich Eckhardt, no no all its gd , but there error in connection now, u can give me a hint how to create a good connection with mysql database and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a file called DB.php and add the below and include it the file whenever you need or you can just call in the file. Try not to practice repetitive.

```
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('project');
```

Get the temperature value and reassign it to yes or no:

```
    if($temperature == "ON_1"){
           $temperature == "Yes";
    }
    else{
           $temperature == "No";
    }
```

Get the humidity value and reassign it to yes or no:

```
if($humidity == "ON_2"){
   $humidity == "Yes";
}
else{
   $humidity == "No";
}
```

add details into your SQL connections:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO actions ".
   "(humidity,temperature) ".
   "VALUES ".
   "('$humidity','$temperature')";

$results = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $results )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
```

The above method will help you check if the data is entered properly.

Comment: thanks Smit  ,but there are an error because i'm using mysql and your SQL connections is used in mysqli .I want to use Mysql so you can give me a hint to how to solve the error connection and thanks again.

Comment: @alichokor i have appended my answer based on your request.